# How to package blackberry libraries

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have developed a UIApplication that uses another project of type "library".
How do I package the Application and the library together in one package?

Comment: First question - what is the package? Distribution, one cod files or something else? Could you also say why do you want to have them in one package? And what are you using JDE, Eclipse or BB Ant tools?

Comment: 1- I want to package them into .code file to upload to Appworld.
2- The library project is Auto-run in startup.
3- My main application contacts with the library throw RunTimeStore 
4- I am using Eclipse.

Comment: I never submitted app to AppWorld. Is it possible to submit several cod files? If yes, you need to submit your cod file and library cod file.

Comment: Yes, It's possible to submit several cod file, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Build Configuration path of the application in the application settings to include the library you want to package with your application.

I hope this helps